# honda civic 2005 overheating

Tags: radiator, overheating

I have a honda civic 2005, is getting overheat, the radiator is almost empty, but the reservoir container is over the top; when I stop on a traffic light the temperature gauge is slowly goes up, but when I move, it goes down. the radiator is getting empty but the it doesn't go anywhere but the reservoir. how can I fix this???

Answer (score 1):

This era of Honda Civics are commonly reported to blow their head gaskets.

If your radiator is getting empty, it's likely all going into the cylinders. Check your oil immediately, and see if it's milky/muddy. If so, get the car booked in for repairs, driving it with a blown head gasket can lead to catastrophic failure of the engine.

Comment: The oil is fine, the coolant is going to the reservoir container, someone suggest to get a new radiator cap ( i haven't change mine in 11 years ), he had the same issue with coolant going to the reservoir and that was it. ill try it today.